# Enhancing jQuery forms with jQuery Theme

Tags: jquery, forms

I find a solution which address the integration of jQuery theme with html forms. It traverse the html form tags and add theme ui css to them.

In this way, I don't need to add css class to all my input, radio, checkbox or select tags?

I wonder if this solution has any performance issues? Are there any better ways to add jQuery theme to forms?

Edited:
I also find this solution useful for lay-outing the forms with css frame works.
For example if you use YAML, you need to have below code to align you form elements.

```
<div class="ym-fbox ym-fbox-text">
<label for="firstname">
      First name
    </label><input id="firstname" type="text" size="20" name="firstname"></input>
</div>

<div class="ym-fbox ym-fbox-text">
<label for="lastname">
      Last name
    </label><input id="lastname" type="text" size="20" name="lastname"></input>
</div>

<div class="ym-fbox ym-fbox-text">
<label for="age">
      Age
    </label><input id="age" type="text" size="20" name="age">"></input>
</div>
```

Every `input`  tag and its `label` must be warped by a `div` with mentioned class. So I can use jQuery to add above dynamically to my codes. If I don't want to use it, I should repeat the `<div class="ym-fbox ym-fbox-text"></div>` to **each** input tag

Comment: What's wrong with CSS? Your solution will most probably be less performant.

Comment: It is Nothing wrong with CSS. I have **lots** of forms and in this way I only add this widget and it will update all form elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement javascript code to traverse the dom tree and add css attributes/classnames it will naturally cause some performance loss (and might even lead to browser compatibilty issues depending on how robust your javascript code is).

It is not a huge performance loss, but I would recommend to instead do the job and add the needed css markup in your templates instead.